# Consulta en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola como puede mostrar este resultado de consulta en php saludos

```
SELECT SUM(etiqueta1) FROM 48233a
```

Comment: Saludos, existen muchos tutoriales en internet sobre esto incluso videos, intentalo cuando tengas errores al intentarlo acude aca, en tanto checa esto: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Gracias saludos

Answer (score 4):

Escribe este código en un editor y guárdalo en un archivo de nombre `ejemplo.php` (recuerda que antes debes haber creado la base de datos y creado datos de ejemplo como hemos visto anteriormente). Recuerda también que debes cambiar y poner tus propios valores en las funciones `mysqli_connect` y `mysqli_select_db`.

También cambia los valores de la tabla, en este caso yo puse los siguientes

```
 - nombre
 - apellidos
 - direccion
 - telefono
 - edad
```

Así que el código sería el siguiente, es una estructura muy básica, seá util para lo que vas hacer.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","Password");
mysqli_select_db($link, "nombre_baseDatos");

$tildes = $link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //Para que se muestren las tildes (OPCIONAL)
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT SUM(column_name) 
                                FROM table_name WHERE condition");
mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0);
$extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "- Nombre: ".$extraido['nombre']."<br/>";
echo "- Apellidos: ".$extraido['apellidos']."<br/>";
echo "- Dirección: ".$extraido['direccion']."<br/>";
echo "- Teléfono: ".$extraido['telefono']."<br/>";
echo "- Edad: ".$extraido['edad']."<br/>";
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Gracias lo probaremos saludos

Answer (score 0):

INTENTA CON ESTO

```
 1-crea tu conexón a la base de datos 
 $conn=new mysqli("localhost","usuario","contraseña","base_de_datos_seleccionar");
 $sel=$conn->query("Select campo1,campo2,campo3 FROM nombre_de_mi_tabla");
 while ($filas=$sel->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $filas['mi_campo'];
    echo $filas['mi_campo'];
    echo $filas['mi_campo'];
  }
```

Comment: Gracias lo intentare asi

Comment: DE NADA AMIGO!  ;) , LO OLVIDABA DES PUES DEL ÚLTIMO ECHO AGREGA ESTO , ES MUY IMPORTANTE 


mysqli_free_result($sel);
mysqli_close($conn);